# Garbage value in jtable after adding row dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, garbage

I have `JTable` which has few columns.In that I have `JComboBox`. At program start I want them to be empty.I have one `JButton` on click action of button i have the code to add row dynamically in table.

But after adding the row i get garbage value in the cell having `JComboBox`. As shown in below figure :

[image]

And here is the code :

Code to add JComboBox in table

```
// Create columns names
String columnNames[] = { "Item", "Sun Item", "Required Quantity","Price","Gross Amount" };

// Create some data
final String dataValues[][] =
    {
        { "", "", "","","", },
    };

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames);

    // Create a new table instance
    table = new JTable( tableModel );

updateItemCombo();
TableColumn itemColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
itemColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboItem));

public void updateItemCombo(){
    Vector<String> s = new Vector<String>();
    try{
        setConnectin();
        String str = "select * from ItemTable";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String nm = rs.getString("Item_Name");
            s.add(nm);
        }
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e2){
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> modelData = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(s);
    comboItem.setModel(modelData);
}
```

Code to add row dynamically on button click :

```
 btnAddOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            tableModel.addRow(dataValues);
            tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    });
```

What should i do to remove this garbage value from table? Please help

Comment: `Vector`? Seriously? What is this, 1991??

Comment: @BoristheSpider, its what the JDK API supports.

Comment: It just a sample code.I have tried with `vector`.I want to remove that `garbage` from cell of `Jtable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addRow(...) method takes a 1-Dimensional array as a parameter. You are attempting to add a 2-Dimensional array.

Also, do not use:

```
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

it is the job of the TableModel to invoke the appropriate fireXXX() method, which by the way in this case would be `fireTableRowsInserted(...)`.

Comment: Thank you.In addRow() method i was attempted to add 2-Dimensional array.Now i have updated that array with 1-Dimensional array.